# How to stop looping same data in foreach laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

Below are the results i get:

=======================================================
**Cakupan Keilmuan**
Superspesialis, misalnya: taksonomi jamur, atau studi Jepang
**Cakupan Keilmuan**
Spesialis, misalnya: fisiologi tumbuhan atau ekologi pesisir, atau studi Asia Timur
**Cakupan Keilmuan**
Cabang ilmu, misalnya: botani atau studi wilayah
**Cakupan Keilmuan**
Disiplin ilmu, misalnya: biologi atau sosiologi
========================================================
How I can get the results like this below?

========================================================
**Cakupan Keilmuan**
Superspesialis, misalnya: taksonomi jamur, atau studi Jepang
Spesialis, misalnya: fisiologi tumbuhan atau ekologi pesisir, atau studi Asia Timur
Cabang ilmu, misalnya: botani atau studi wilayah
Disiplin ilmu, misalnya: biologi atau sosiologi

========================================================

```
//My Codes In Controller:

$isi = DB::table('tb_indikator_penilaian')
        ->leftJoin('tb_sub_unsur_penilaian', 'tb_sub_unsur_penilaian.id_sub_unsur', '=', 'tb_indikator_penilaian.id_sub_unsur_penilaian')
        ->leftJoin('tb_unsur_penilaian', 'tb_indikator_penilaian.id_unsur_penilaian', '=', 'tb_unsur_penilaian.id_unsur')
        ->select('tb_indikator_penilaian.indikator', 'tb_sub_unsur_penilaian.sub_unsur_penilaian', 'tb_unsur_penilaian.unsur_penilaian', 'tb_indikator_penilaian.nilai')
        ->where('tb_indikator_penilaian.id_unsur_penilaian', '=', 4)
        ->get();

return view('form-akreditasi', compact('isi'));


//My Codes In View:

<td data-title="Indikator" class="string">
    @foreach($isi as $dataindikator)
       <b>{{ $dataindikator->sub_unsur_penilaian }}</b><br>
       {{ $dataindikator->indikator }}<br>
    @endforeach
</td>
```

Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
<?php $header = null ?>
<td data-title="Indikator" class="string">
    @foreach($isi as $dataindikator)
       @if ($header != $dataindikator->sub_unsur_penilaian)
           <b>{{ $dataindikator->sub_unsur_penilaian }}</b><br>
           <?php $header = $dataindikator->sub_unsur_penilaian ?>
       @endif
       {{ $dataindikator->indikator }}<br>
    @endforeach
</td>
```

This way you only print the header the first time it is found/changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use laravel >= 5.3, use blade loop variable:

```
<td data-title="Indikator" class="string">
    @foreach($isi as $dataindikator)
       @if ($loop->first)
           <b>{{ $dataindikator->sub_unsur_penilaian }}</b><br>
       @endif
       {{ $dataindikator->indikator }}<br>
    @endforeach
</td>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable